# How to handle big legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My barplot has very long leyends but I really need them to be presented as informative as possible, either if I get the legend with the plot or with a separate command. Im more o less new to ggplot2 and I have tried moving the leyend to the botton or changing the font size but it doesnt make the job. Perhaps you have some suggestion?

Here I give you a couple of photos so you get the idea

The first one is the plot with the legend

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = muestra, y = frecuencia, fill = taxonomia)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

And this one is the plot without the leyend

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = muestra, y = frecuencia, fill = taxonomia)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I understand the problem, while reducing the text and legend spacing might help, it might be somewhat instructive to look at how other authors in your field  (I assume microbiology/metagenomics related) are handling similar plots and legends and learn from them. If you post an example of a great plot that handles the legend really well, maybe we could figure out how to do this in ggplot.

Comment: To expand on the great comment by @teunbrand, you could shorten the text and supply the relevant keys in your figure text.